# Android File IO Interface Class

Tags: java, android, file-io

I did some reading on the API for File IO and read the following blog post: http://techknock.blogspot.com/2008/05/file-hadling-in-android.html. His code works fine when everything is in the same activity. But what I am trying to do is create an IOInterface class that I can use to open multiple databases to populate multiple lists.

**ListA.java**

```
public class ListA
{
    public List<ClassA> list;
    private final String DBA = "dbA";
    private IOInterface database;

    public List()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
        database = new IOInterface();
    }

    ...

    public void initListA() throws IOException
    {
        database.openForWriting(DBA);

        String myStr = new String("content");
        database.dos.writeBytes(myStr);
        database.dos.flush();
        database.dos.close();
    }
}
```

**IOInterface.java**

```
public class IOInterface
{
    public DataOutputStream dos;
    private FileOutputStream fos;

    public void openForWriting(String database)
    {
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(database, Content.MODE_PRIVATE);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse underlines `fos = openFileOutput(database, Content.MODE_PRIVATE);`. With the comment that `openFileOutput()` does not exist. The resolution to this is to extend the IOInteface class as an Activity. I suppose then `openFileOutput()` is a method of an activity class.

So my question is how do accomplish what I am trying to do? Standard Java file io such as:

```
File fp = new File("database");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fp);
```

does not work. It catches a FileNotFoundException. This has to be doable though. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `openFileOutput()` is contained in the `Context` class, so you can pass an instance of this class to your method that opens files. And you should always use methods from `Context` when you want to work with files.

You can read about using the internal and external storages in the [development guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Unbelievable ... I was just about to hit Post and you've posted the exact same answer! +1.

Comment: I am importing the Context class: import android.content.Context. So why then does Eclipse say "The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type IOInterface" unless I extend IOInterface as an Activity? I read through the API of FileInputStream (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and didn't see any references to it needing to be an activity.

Comment: @njozwiak: you're probably very new to Java. Importing a class just means you can use it (create an instance, extend, etc.). `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`. Method `openFileOutput()` is contained in the `Context` class - that's why `openFileInput()` is only available inside of `Activity` instance, but not in your IOInterface.

Comment: @Arhimed: yes, I am new to Java and specifically Android. Almost all of my work is in C and on embedded systems so forgive me if my questions seem obvious.

If Activity is a subclass of Context, then why is it needed to access a method of Context. It seems to me that if a Dog is a subclass of Pet, that Pet and it's functions should be accessible without all of it's subclasses. 

In my case, if Activity is necessary to access member functions of Context. How do open a file for io without creating and launching a separate activity?

Comment: @njozwiak: Context is a public abstract class. It can not be instantiated directly. Activity is indirect subclass of Context. THere are 2 intermidiate classes -

Comment: Sorry for the previous post - it is incomplete.

Comment: @njozwiak: `Context` is a public abstract class. It can not be instantiated directly. `Activity` is an indirect subclass of `Context`. There are 2 intermidiate classes - `ContextWrapper` and `ContextThemeWrapper`. All of the `Context` descendants have `openFileInput()`. So to call `openFileInput()` you need an instance of non-abstract `Context` (abstract classes can not be instantiated), and `Activity` is one of suitable choices. You can also use `openFileInput()` within `Application` or `Service` since they are also `Context` sublasses.

Comment: @Arhimed: ah, the abstraction is what I missed. That makes sense. Looking back at the API page for Context I the words jumping out at me too. "This is an abstract class". I appreciate the help guys.