# Request information from Android APP by Widget

Tags: android

What I would like to do is get the value of variable stored in the main Application when the widget is first installed. Every time the variable is updated the main application sends it to the widget using sendBroadcast(intent); However, this means the first time the widget is installed it displays nothing.

Can you send a request to the application for data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I would like to do is get the value of variable stored in the main Application when the widget is first installed.

An `AppWidgetProvider` is part of your application. It has access to all your databases, files, preferences, or other data stores. Simply use that data when you create your app widget in `onUpdate()`.

> Every time the variable is updated the main application sends it to the widget using sendBroadcast(intent);

That is silly. The main application can use `AppWidgetManager` to update the app widget directly.

Comment: Thanks for that. See the problem is I am reading in information from files, doing some sums then having them as a variable that is worked on and saved to the file every time it is updated. I was hoping to just send the info over to the app instead of having to read the file from the widget which I cannot get to work. The openFileInput doesn't seem to work in appWidget..

Comment: @user1235720: `openFileInput()` is a method on `Context`. `AppWidgetProvider` is not a `Context`, but you are passed in a `Context` as a parameter to methods like `onUpdate()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316887/android-file-io-interface-class) and worked it out. I finally think I've grasped it!